# IndexError When Iterating Through N-Dimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, python-2.x

As mentioned in the title, I am getting an IndexError when iterating through a n-dimensional array. What I am trying to do with the code, is to set portions of the matrix to 0 and keep the rest of the data.

I also realize that selecting an element in a n-dimensional array should be array[row#][column#] but it is just a problem with my naming convention which I will fix later. However, the values are correct.

```
currentMatrix = np.array(ast.literal_eval(safety.iloc[i]), dtype=np.int)
currentMatrix.shape = (27,15)

tpHeight = int(df['touchH'].iloc[i])
tpWidth = int(df['touchW'].iloc[i])

fullRows = np.arange(15)
fullColumns = np.arange(27)

beforeAreaColumns = np.arange(df['touchX'].iloc[i] - 1, dtype=np.int)
afterAreaColumns = np.arange(df['touchX'].iloc[i] + tpWidth - 1, dtype=np.int)

beforeAreaRows = np.arange(df['touchY'].iloc[i] - 1, dtype=np.int)
afterAreaRows = np.arange(df['touchY'].iloc[i] + tpHeight - 1, dtype=np.int)

print beforeAreaColumns #returns [0 1 2 3 4 5] at i = 0

currentMatrix[beforeAreaColumns][fullRows] = 0
currentMatrix[afterAreaColumns][fullRows] = 0
currentMatrix[fullColumns][beforeAreaRows] = 0
currentMatrix[fullColumns][afterAreaRows] = 0
```

The error I receive is:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-342e7c1b89ae> in <module>()
     26     print beforeAreaColumns
     27     
---> 28     currentMatrix[beforeAreaColumns][fullRows] = 0
     29     currentMatrix[afterAreaColumns][fullRows] = 0
     30     currentMatrix[fullColumns][beforeAreaRows] = 0

IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6
```

From my understanding, I am getting the error because the code tries to find an index in position 7 when there are only 6 positions. However, I am not sure why it tries index 6 when the array stops at index 5.

I tried changing the code so that it uses for loops, for example:

```
for beforeAreaColumn in beforeAreaColumns:
    for fullRow in fullRows:
        currentMatrix[beforeAreaColumn][fullRow] = 0
```

but I get the same error. The above code is written and run on Python 2.7.

Comment: Maybe `print currentMatrix[6][10]` is problematic? Not line 28, but 27.

Comment: Oh I had forgotten to remove it from the original code but it is not the problem. I just had it there to test whether it would give an output or not.